# Buttons in a html table not aligned

Tags: php, html-table

I have created a search box that allows you to search inside a MySQL database using PHP.
The search results are displayed in a table (or multiple tables if there are more records marching the keyword).

In the last two columns there are two buttons to change some parameters to the record in the database.
However, the right side button (between the `<td>` tag) seems to be poorly aligned with the relative header.

I attach a screenshot and the code.

```
echo '<table style="width:100%" border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<th><p>Last Name:</p><th>';
    echo '<th><p>Student ID:</p><th>';

    echo '<th><p>Sell:</p><th>';
    echo '<th><p>Return Item:</p><th>';

    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td>'.$results['lastname'].'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$results['studentid'].'<td>';

            echo '<td><form action="BOOKS_changestatus.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Sell"></td>';
            echo '<td><form action="BOOKS_changestatus.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Return"></td>';





    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<br>';
```

[image]

Comment: You did not close the form. You did not close any tags. They are closed like `</td>`.

Comment: Close your forms, remove the `<br>`, add a `</table>`.

Comment: and after you've done the above, maybe go and study the basics of HTML markup again :-). Another small thing, the "border" attribute in a table is deprecated in HTML5, you should be using CSS styles instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: And you could use a hyperlink instead of your forms, to make it simpler, since they're using GET requests anyway. You can always change the style to make them look like buttons.

Comment: Whatever the reason for the misalignment, I doubt mysql has much to do with it!

Comment: Do I just use an hyperlink and link it to the PHP file? Just like <a href="myurl/sell.php">Sell</a>

Comment: yes, you can do that, you probably just need to provide an argument on the querystring so it knows what action to perform. e.g. something like `<a href="BOOKS_changestatus.php?id=1&action=sell">Sell</a>` and then PHP will look for `$_GET["id"]` and `$_GET["action"]` to know what to do, and which item to do it to.

Comment: As you can see from the latest answer I posted, I closed all the tags but the appearance is still weird.

Comment: "weird" is not something we can fix. Also please don't post answers which don't resolve the problem. Instead, edit the question. If something is still wrong, please post a screenshot so we can understand.

Comment: Yeah sorry :( I mean that it looks the same. Nothing changed although I closed all the tags.

Comment: did you remove the `<br>` tags as well? They don't belong between table rows. A row will always be on a new line anyway.

Comment: All your th rows are wrong too. You've created new th tags instead of closing the originals. `<th><p>Last Name:</p><th>` should be `<th><p>Last Name:</p></th>`. Same for all the others. A couple of the td rows also have the same issue! Go back and check every line of your code in detail, and make sure you understand the correct HTML syntax for the elements you're using. I don't know if these are a misunderstanding or simply a typo, but small details are important in all programming activities. Double-check everything. It's tedious but necessary.

Comment: I don't know what editor you use to write your code, but find one which uses syntax highlighting and knows HTML and you might spot this kind of thing more easily. It would be easier if the HTML was outside the PHP `echo` .statements too, then the syntax is not cluttered with PHP guff. Close the PHP block with a `?>` and re-open it later with a `<?php` when you need to actually execute some script. You can inject PHP data into the middle of the HTML easily e.g. `<td><?php echo $results['lastname']; ?></td>`. This is much cleaner and neater (and easier to write) than billions of echo statements

Answer (score 1):

You have two open forms and one table, all of which aren't closed.

Also why do you use different forms which send to the same PHP file? One form is enough, I think:

```
<?php

echo '<table style="width:100%" border="1">';
echo '<tr>';

echo '<th><p>Last Name:</p><th>';
echo '<th><p>Student ID:</p><th>';

echo '<th><p>Sell:</p><th>';
echo '<th><p>Return Item:</p><th>';

echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>'.$results['lastname'].'<td>';
echo '<td>'.$results['studentid'].'<td>';

echo '<td><form action="BOOKS_changestatus.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Sell"></form></td>';
echo '<td><form action="BOOKS_changestatus.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Return"></form></td>';

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Your `</form>`s should be inside the `<td></td>`

Comment: probably there are two forms because they have different purposes and submit different values - you can see that in the code. Although since they both use GET, a hyperlink would have done the same job more simply.

Comment: @kerbholz You are right, it's edit.

Comment: No that's still not right, the `</form>` tags (both of them!) need to be inside the same td where the `<form>` is. What you've done is a) invalid and b) will also screw up the layout even more by creating an extra cell where there shouldn't be one.

Comment: Edited, but wrong ;) They should be placed right after the `<input type="submit"`s and before the `</td>`.

Comment: Yeah.. my bad, it's done.